# Representation-finite finite rings

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Can the finite representation-finite rings with at most 2 simple modules be classified?

Is there a non-serial local representation-finite finite ring?

Comment: If the ring is an algebra over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, then the answer to the first question is yes: Up to Morita equivalence, they are $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$, $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}[x]/(x^2)$, $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}\times \mathbb{F}_{q^m}$. If the characteristic of the field is not prime, but at least square-free, you additionally have $\mathbb{F}_{p_1^m}\times \mathbb{F}_{p_2^n}$. Furthermore, the characteristic of the field has to be cube-free. I don't know what to expect if the characteristic is a square. For example $\mathbb{Z}/(p^2)$ definitely satisfies the assumption, but I don't know if more

Comment: Sorry, the above was the answer for at most $2$ indecomposables. But there are not too many more if you ask the ring to be an algebra over a field. Then, in addition you have $\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{F}_{q^n}&M\\0&\mathbb{F}_{q^m}\end{pmatrix}$ where $M$ is an $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$-$\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$-bimodule and since the category of such bimodules is semisimple, there are only finitely many such modules up to isomorphism.